# OOM when assigning image to marker on google map

Tags: android

I am trying to load an image that is 175 by 175 as google map marker

```
Marker marker =  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc)
                    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(chrctr.getThumbResId())));
```

The problem is that I am expecting to have many of these. If I add 10 of these then then app the crashes with out of memory

How can I resolve this given  I am using gooogle map v2 and using the BitmapDescriptorFactory

Thank you

Comment: That's approx 12MB of memory needed just for the images.  If you are using a 16MB heap (quite likely) that doesn't leave much room.  You will have to scale the images down when loading or use less memory somewhere else.  You could also try using a large heap size but that's not guaranteed on all devices.

Comment: How can I scale them down? I want them to occupying the same physical size.  Also how did you come up with 12 MB?

Comment: I did calculations (it is 4 * 175*175) = 0.12MB not 12 MB. If you can tell me how you calculated yours then that will be great

Comment: `If I add 10 of these`

Comment: Ahhh good point, but that makes it 1.2MB :)